# Why can't I log into the Trello iPhone app using my Google account? 

Tags: trello, iphone

I'm using the Trello iOS app and I can't seem to get in with my Google account. I can, however, log in using the browser on my iPhone.

Comment: I am a member of the Trello team, submitting a question we received over email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The app has been updated since its first version, and you can now login using either a username and password or your Google account.

You can also use Trello in Safari on your iPhone or iPad.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot login to the iPhone app using oAuth: you MUST have a password, and login using your **username** and password.  If you just set a password and have logged in using oAuth on the web and try to use your email and password, the App crash's and cannot be reopened without it crashing.  You must use your username, not email to login on the iPhone.